# Why value of p is false?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here i am try to check if a particular value is exists in the column or not .if exists then I want to add field else I don't want .but p value is false even though the data exists in that particular column .it is showing true for the first time. from the next time onwards it is false.
$('#attach').click((e) => {
e.preventDefault();

```
    var len = $('#tablefd03 tbody tr').length;
    debugger;

  
    if (len == 0) {
        $("input[id=fd03_Fd03FormFieldSeq]").val(1);
    }
    else {
        var val = prompt("enter the previous order ");
        if (!val) return;
        else if (isNaN(val)) return alert("Please enter a  number !");
        else {
            var p = false;
            $('#tablefd03 tbody tr').each(function (index, el) {
               
                debugger;
                if ($(el).children().eq(4).text() == parseInt(val)) {
                    

                    //s = value;

                    p = true;
                    
                    

                }
                else {
                    p = false;
                }
            })
            if (p) {
                $("input[id=fd03_Fd03FormFieldSeq]").val(parseInt(val) + 1);
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
          }
       
    }
        
    var form = $('#myform').serialize();
    if (!$('#myform').valid()) {
        return
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "/FormDesign/Attach",
        method: "POST",
        data: form,

    })
        .done(function (data) {
            if (data.isValid) {
                //var len=$('#tablefd03 tr').length);
                notif({
                    type: "success",
                    msg: "Attached successfully",
                    timeout: 5000,

                })

                alert("Data Loaded: " + JSON.stringify(data));
                //$('#h').replaceWith("#p")
                $('#_view-all').html(data.html.fd02partialview);
                $('#partialfd03').html(data.html.fd03partialview);
                sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(data));
                reset();
            }
            alert("failed")

        });
})
```

Comment: I don't know exactly what it is you're trying to do here, but you should really narrow this down to a problem you can reproduce and then post the relevant code.  There's no context here to help you.  Also, frankly, this seems a bit of a nighmarish way to do something, and if you post more context we might be able to help you clean it up and make it easier to understand and implement. :-)

Comment: Sorry man, I am a terrible coder. here i m checking if a particular vaue is existed in a particular column or not  .if exists then I want to add the next field

Comment: Is `$(el).children().eq(4)` the jQuery element you expect? Is `parseInt(val)` the value you expect?

Comment: Could you please explain more? It is hard to understand.

Comment: Hei man i want to check if the val is existed or not in that column

Comment: It looks like it’s because of the `each` loop: `p` is set in every iteration, so `p` only has the value based on the final iteration.

Comment: @SebastianSimon you are right . if p value is true I wan to set  $("input[id=fd03_Fd03FormFieldSeq]").val(parseInt(val) + 1); else I want to return false

Comment: So, you prompt somebody for an order number, and then you want to pull the data for that order out of the DOM itself?  You should really make a reproducible code sample, along with the HTML.  It's hard to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, the problem is with your `each` loop.  If the last row isn't the one you're looking for, then `p` is going to be `false` because your code loops through the entire array of rows.  What you want to do instead is find the row you're looking for and return as soon as you have it, or return falsey if you don't.

I haven't used jQuery in a long time, so I'll write up an answer for you with regular JavaScript.  This is very easy to do with [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```
const rowEl = [...document.querySelectorAll('#tablefd03 tbody tr')].find((rowEl) => {
  return [...rowEl.querySelectorAll('td')][4]?.textContent === val;
});
```

In this code, `rowEl` will contain the row you want, if found.  Otherwise `rowEl` will be undefined.

The `.find()` method loops through each element of the array until the callback function returns truthy.

We check each row's cell with index `4` (if exists) for `textContent` and compare against `val`.  If they're equal, this callback will return `true`, which will cause `.find()` to stop searching and return the current row.  This will be assigned to `rowEl`.

You didn't provide any HTML to test with, so I'll leave any debugging or implementation to you.  Hopefully this gets you started.